# Covering Lemma for Infinite Collection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading a proof of Vitali's lemma in Wheeden's Measure and Integral that I have questions about.

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite exterior measure and $K$ a collection of cubes $Q$ covering $E$. We index the size of a cube $Q \in K$ by writing $Q = Q(t)$, where $t$ is the side length of $Q$.

Let $K_1 = K$. Let $t_1^* = \sup\{t: Q= Q(t) \in K_1\}$. Assume $t_1^*$ is finite. Choose $Q_1 = Q_1(t_1) \in K_1$ such that $t_1 > \frac 1 2 t_1^*$. Now split $K_1 = K_2 \cup K_2'$, where $K_2$ has cubes in $K_1$ disjoint from $Q_1$ and $K_2'$ has cubes in $K_1$ intersecting $Q_1$. Let $\hat{Q_1}$ denote the cube concentric with $Q_1$ with side length $5t_1$.

We continue this selection process for $j = 2,3,\dots$ by letting $t_j^* = \sup\{t:Q = Q(t) \in K_j\}$ by choosing $Q_j \in K_j$ with $t_j > \frac 1 2 t_j^*$, and splitting $K_j = K_{j+1} \cup K_{j+1}'$, where $K_{j+1}$ are cubes disjoint from $Q_j$.

Two claims I don't understand:

(1) Every cube in $K_2'$ is contained in $\hat{Q_1}$. Why do we need to scale the side length by 5 for infinite collections but 3 for finite collections?

(2) $t_j^* \ge t_{j+1}^*$. We choose $Q_j$ to be a relatively large cube, but not the largest. Why do cubes with side lengths larger than that of $Q_j$ not belong to $K_{j+1}$?